# Regex pattern for London postcodes not matching

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to create a regex pattern for Javascript to test the provided postcode value to find out whether it matches a London postcode. [London postcodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_postal_district) start with either:

- EC, WC, NW, SE or SW
- E#, N#, W# (where # is 1 through to 9, single digit)

My regex pattern is: `^[nN|eE|wW][1-9]{1}|[ecEC|wcWC|nw|NW|seSE|swSW]{2}`, and for some reason it seems to think that a value starting with *CE* matches? when I haven't specified this...

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Use `(?:...)` instead of `[...]`

Comment: [ecEC] mean all these 4 characters are accepted in any order. So even CE would match. As suggested in above comment change your brackets.

Comment: Try to see what your pattern means by putting it on some online regex debuggers.

Comment: @Thefourthbird `^(?:nN|eE|wW)[1-9]{1}|(?:ecEC|wcWC|nw|NW|seSE|swSW){2}` doesn't appear to be valid after changing, it's not matching anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
pattern = new RegExp('^(?:(?:n|e|w)[1-9]|(?:ec|wc|[ns]w|se))','gi')
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/M7XIDV/7)

---

After your comment I thought you might want to match exactly all the london postal district as per your link in OP.

```
pattern = new RegExp('^(?:e(?:[1-9]|1[0-8]|20)|n(?:[1-9]|1\d|2[012])|w(?:[1-9]|1[0-4])|ec[1-4]|wc[12]|nw(?:[1-9]|1[01])|se(?:[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])|sw(?:[1-9]|1\d|20)) [a-z]+(?: [a-z']+)*$','gi')
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/M7XIDV/9)

You may have to double up the backslashes.

Comment: This is great, seems to match, but postcodes are longer than 2 characters and the regex fails after 2 characters, kind of need it to be true throughout